# is there any way to add blank row with @"" in uitableview just after where all dynamic data has been populated :iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i am having dynamically created `UITableView`. I want to add 3 dummy row when the table view have ben populated from array.

My scenario is that when there is sufficient data in the `UITableView`, then at the bottom of uitable dummy rows with blank text.

In this way even if there is 40 records, by scrolling up the last two rows will be visible.
suppose my array count is 14 (which is dynamic/not always 14) then how do i add three blank row in index path 14,15,16 and setting their text as:

```
cell.textlabel.text=@"";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do like this.

retune no of row like this below.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
return [array count]+2; 
}
```

After that manage this in cellRowAtindexPath method like shown in below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
[tableView setPagingEnabled:NO];
//[tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"longDotedLine.png"]]];

  if (indexPath.row < [array count]) {
      cell.textLabel.text = @"Test Data";
  } else {
      cell.textLabel.text = @"";
  }


return cell;

}
```

Try this may be this help you.

Thanks,
MinuMaster.

Comment: thank you very much i was able to understand logic but objective c sentences is really puzzling me!

Comment: This works great, but is there anyway i can open a custom view, only and only when this static cell is tapped. The rest of the table is handled by Storyboards/Master-Detail Template.

Comment: @SiddharthGupta Yes you can do this. Add same condition in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. And add you code for open custom view in else part.

Answer (score 1):

Add some variable which has count three more than arra count.Like if ur array has 12 elements,The variable  say totalRow=[array Count]+3;
Comapare this in cellForRowAtIndexPAth delegate and do your operation

Answer (score 1):

I am surprise why such question arised?? What is problem in detecting the Last Record of Dynamic Data?

If you are taking any number of dynamic data in **Array** then simply you can **Keep RowCount +1** and check if last record is reached in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If yes, then simply add a *Your Last statement*  i.e `cell.textLabel.text = @"";` for last record.

Comment: thanks for criticizing! but objective c language is really stuffing me try to learn!thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return ([array count] + 3);
}
```